# Is there any way to display the 'reviews' section from a Facebook page on my webpage?

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to simply display the 'Reviews' Section from my company FB page on our company Intranet site (HTML page) I can't seem to figure out how to do this with any of the tools that FB offers for developers, or through the graph API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite familier with the reviews, but a quick glance at the API docs shows reviews as being linked to Apps, not Pages.

Once you have an access token, you should be able to query the reviews of an app like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/reviews?access_token=<access_token>
```